# check file's width and height before upload in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload

I have a case where I need to check the heigh, width and size of a file I upload. I checked the size and included it in the conditional expression. But I can't get the height and width in the same way. I have read about using a `new Image()` but when I use it in code, it doesn't work well. Maybe I didn't put it in the right place. Below is my code right now, just can check the size of the file.

```
onFileInputChange(event: any): FileReader {
    let files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
    return reader
  }

  onThemeChange(event: any) {
let imageType = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg']
this.onFileInputChange(event).onload = (e: any) => {
  const image = new Image()
  image.src = this.upload_header
  image.onload = () => {
    if (
      event.target.files.length > 0 &&
      event.target.files[0].size < 26214400 &&
      imageType.includes(event.target.files[0].type) &&
      image.width > 500 &&
      image.height > 100
    ) {
      this.upload_header = e.target.result
      console.log(image)
      console.log(image.height)
    } else {
      this.errorUploadFile = true
    }
  }
}
```

}
I want if all the conditions are met, the selected file (in this case is an image) will replace the existing one. I have edited my code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
      this.image.size = file.size;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = evt => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => {
          this.image.width = img.width;
          this.image.height = img.height;
          this.imageLoaded = true;
        }
        img.src = evt.target.result;
      }
```

---

---

Would you like to try the following?

This is the source code that I tested.

```
  <div>
    <input type="file" @change="onThemeChange" />
    {{ meta }}
  </div>
```

---

```
 export default class ComponentName extends Vue {
     meta: any = null;
    
        onThemeChange(event: any) {
          const file = event.target.files[0];
    
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          reader.onload = (evt: any) => {
            let img = new Image();
            const meta = (img.onload = () => {
              return {
                size: event.target.files[0].size,
                width: img.width,
                height: img.height,
              };
            });
            img.src = evt.target.result;
            this.meta = meta();
          };
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my `onThemeChange()` function. My problem now is that I got the width and height of the previous image, not the image file I really choose.

Comment: Can you try in case meta already has data? Is it possible to get the height and width of the photo you choose? In my case, if I already had the data, selecting the new image makes me only able to get the height and width of the old image, not the image I selected

Answer (score -1):

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
const image = new Image();
fileReader.onload = function (e) {
    image.src = e.target.result;
    image.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work well. Where should I put it in my code?